# How to define a parameter

Tags: constraints, cplex

I want to write a constraint and for that, I need to define a parameter called the travel time of the vehicle 's' from node 'm' to 'n'.

I have defined the travel time in tuple form i.e. given below:

```
int num_road = 6;
range Roadno = 1..num_road;

tuple Road {
 int Road_num;
 int from_node;
 int to_node;
 int travel_time;
}

Road Roaddata [Roadno] = [
 <1, 15, 21, 2>,
 <2, 21, 15, 2>,
 <3, 21, 30, 2>,
 <4, 30, 21, 2>,
 <5, 15, 30, 1>,
 <6, 30, 15, 1>
];
```

Now I have to use this tuple data to write down the constraint i.e. given below.

```
NT =24;

forall (s in M,m in B, n in B:m!=n, tau in 1..Tm_ij[n][i][j],t in 1..NT-tau){
    pos[s][m][t+tau] + pos[s][n][t] <= 1;
}
```

Instead of `Tm_ij[n][i][j]` matrix I want to use the data of travel time from the tuple. Please suggest to me how to write this constraint in OPL CPLEX by using tuple data.

[image: The mathematical expression of the constraint is attached]

Answer (score 0):

With "item" you can read your travel time from the tuple set.

```
int num_road = 6;
range Roadno = 1..num_road;

tuple Road {
 key int Road_num;
 key int from_node;
 key int to_node;
 int travel_time;
}

{Road} Roaddata = {
 <1, 15, 21, 2>,
 <2, 21, 15, 2>,
 <3, 21, 30, 2>,
 <4, 30, 21, 2>,
 <5, 15, 30, 1>,
 <6, 30, 15, 1>
};

int NT =24;
range M=1..2;
range B=1..3;

dvar boolean pos[-1000..1000][M][-1000..1000];


subject to
{

forall (s in M,m in B, n in B:m!=n,  tau in 1..item(Roaddata,<n,s,n>).travel_time,t in 1..NT-tau){
    pos[s][m][t+tau] + pos[s][m][t] <= 1;
}
}
```